# Silently download and print PDF document from Java Applet on Windows

Tags: java, windows, pdf, applet

I want to download a PDF and print it. I want to do this completely silently with no dialogue boxes displayed to the user. I am currently using a self-signed applet (will sign using an authority when we deploy). It works as desired on Linux and OS X, but not Windows. On Windows it shows the user a dialogue box to save the file (of type .xps). After the file saves it is sent silently to the printer, so my issue is currently how to get the document to save silently without the user seeing the dialogue. Code below. I'm using Apache PDFBox. I've read I may need to use PrivilegedAction, but I don't see why as the issue isn't that I can't download a file, but that I can't do so silently.

```
/**
 * Print Applet
 * Author: kareem
 * Date: 12-02-20
 * Time: 10:57 AM
 */

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import netscape.javascript.*;

public class PrintApplet extends Applet {
    public void init() {
        String callbackURL = this.getParameter("callbackurl");
        String fileToPrint = this.getParameter("file");
        String successCallback = this.getParameter("successcallback");
        String failureCallback = this.getParameter("failurecallback");
        String published = this.getParameter("published");
        JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        if (fileToPrint == null || callbackURL == null) {
            window.call(failureCallback, new String[] { "Missing required parameters." });
        } else {
            try {
                URL printURL;
                printURL = new URL(fileToPrint);
                PDDocument doc;
                doc = PDDocument.load(printURL);
                doc.silentPrint();
                try {
                    URL updateOrderUrl = new URL(callbackURL);
                    HttpURLConnection updateOrderHTTP = (HttpURLConnection) updateOrderUrl.openConnection();
                    updateOrderHTTP.setDoOutput(true);
                    updateOrderHTTP.setDoInput(true);
                    updateOrderHTTP.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                    String updateOrderData = URLEncoder.encode("printed", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("published", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(published, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(updateOrderHTTP.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(updateOrderData);
                    updateOrderHTTP.getInputStream();
                    out.close();
                    window.call(successCallback, null);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    window.call(failureCallback, new String[] { "Server callback failed." });
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                window.call(failureCallback, new String[] { "Invalid print file URL." });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                window.call(failureCallback, new String[] { "Print file could not be loaded." });
            } catch(PrinterException e) {
                System.out.println("Printer exception: " + e.getMessage());
                window.call(failureCallback, new String[] { e.getMessage() });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? We are printing documents that are susceptible to fraud and a condition of our clients is they are only allowed to be printed once.  So we can't show the user the file or give them a dialogue box that allows them to change the number of copies.

Comment: @Kareem Even if you do not show the dialog, I can always print to a PDF file, or configure the printer driver to send the output to a file. There is no way to ensure that users will print the document just once, and I would personally avoid using such a system, since paper jams can always happen even in the most reliable printers.

Comment: @yms You're correct, a savvy user can easily circumvent such a system. However, it doesn't have to be hack-proof or even close to. It just has to work for the majority of users. Our target audience is not technically sophisticated. I agree it will lead to degradation in UX, but I have to please the client and my hands are tied.

Comment: According to the symptoms you mentioned, I would guess that your method `doc.silentPrint()` is somehow printing to the Microsoft XPS Printer AND to your hardware printer at the same time, hence the save dialog for the .xps file. Can you post some relevant parts of that method?

Comment: I believe you're right. It may have to do with the settings on the machine actually. Will update after some tweaking. As a reference, silentPrint isn't my method, but Apache PDFBox's: http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#silentPrint()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found the answer above in the comments: Our default printer was set to Microsoft XPS document writer.

I am mentioning it here incase anyone glosses over the comments and thinks there is no answer.

Please 1up yms's comment instead of this answer.